# haproxy redirection not working when using same bind port?

Tags: haproxy

Currently there are 3 applications running on their respective ports(5000,30000 and
32000).All these application are working at their respective ports.Now i want to map these 3 applications using an alias name with the help of haproxy.

What i have tried

```
frontend frontend1
    mode    http
    bind *:8080
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/mydomain.pem
    http-request redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }


    acl path-processdesigner              path_beg -i /
    use_backend backend3               if path-processdesigner
    acl path-processdesigner              path_beg -i /processdesigner
    use_backend backend3               if path-processdesigner

frontend frontend2
    mode    http
    bind *:8000
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/mydomain.pem
    http-request redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }

    acl path-processcore                  path_beg -i /
    use_backend backend2               if path-processcore
    acl path-processcore              path_beg -i /processcore
    use_backend backend2               if path-processcore

frontend frontend3
    mode    http

    bind *:80

    acl path-employeeList                 path_beg -i /index
    use_backend backend1               if path-employeeList


backend backend1
    mode    http

    option  httplog
    option  forwardfor
    reqrep  ^([^\ :]+)\ /index/?(.*)$  \1\ /\2

    server  backend1  206.189.22.155:32000


backend backend2
    mode    http

    option  httplog
    option  forwardfor
    reqrep  ^([^\ :]+)\ /processcore/?(.*)$  \1\ /\2

    server  backend2 206.189.22.155:5000

backend backend3
    mode    http

    option  httplog
    option  forwardfor
    reqrep  ^([^\ :]+)\ /processdesigner/?(.*)$  \1\ /\2

    server  backend2 206.189.22.155:30000
```

using this config i can access https://206.189.22.155/processdesigner and http://206.189.22.155/index but when i hit https://206.189.22.155/processcore i get 404 not found.Now if i remove frontend frontend1 from the config completely then https://206.189.22.155/processcore works and shows output.Why does it work only when i remove the frontend1 completely?How can i fix this ? Plz help

> NOTE: All the application are working on their respective ports ie, at http://206.189.22.155:5000/,http://206.189.22.155:32000/ and http://206.189.22.155:30000/.

Answer (score 0):

You have two frontends listening on the same port 443 but only the first frontend will match all request coming on port 443.

Comment: i tried removing the bind 443 but even then it does not work

Comment: my goal is just to use the alias name instead of port number in the url

Comment: @VigneshSwaminathan, port 443 is the default port for https:// requests and used  even if you don't specify a port in the URL. You need to rewrite your configuration to have only one frontend with `bind 443`.

Comment: okay i rewrote the config for only single frontend with bind 443.Can you plz check the update/edited question

Comment: @VigneshSwaminathan the issue in your edit is different from your original question so you need to post a separate question.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/988924/haproxy-redirection-not-working-for-multiple-backends

Comment: ok i posted a new question for this in that link!! It would be helpful if u can answer my question there!!